# ownCloud server or Seafile alternative

Tags: web-apps, file-synchronization, windows-server

I am looking for an alternative to Seafile or ownCloud that can be self hosted.
It should offer a web interface and a client as an alternative.

- I cannot use ownCloud because it is not optimized to be run on a Windows server.
- I cannot use Seafile because it does not work over HTTP or HTTPs.
- I do not want to use Dropbox or similar services.

It should support synchronization of the file system with a Windows client.

It can be open or closed source. Free or paid.

The most important requirement is that the server software can be installed on a Windows server.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
4.0.6 was released and is available on Windows now. So Seafile should completely fulfill your requirements.

**Update**
4.0.1 was officially released a day after I answered this (now up to 4.0.4). I've been running it with HTTP/HTTPS sync ever since and it's worked great. The only problem is that it does not seem to have been released for Windows (server component) yet. I don't know of the ETA on it but if you really want to use it now on Windows, you can run it on Linux in a VM using something like VirtualBox.

If you wait for the Seafile 4.0 release, it will have [support for syncing over HTTP/HTTPS](https://seacloud.cc/group/3/wiki/whats-new-in-the-next-version-4-0/). Right now it is tagged as beta and there is no ETA as far as I'm aware since they missed their own [roadmap date of Nov. 15th](https://seacloud.cc/group/3/wiki/seafile-roadmap/).